# Button in custom Android Toast?

Tags: android, button, android-button, toast

Is it possible to have a button in a Toast?

In theory, yes because you can build a custom Toast from a layout in XML, but I tried to put a button in it and couldn't get it to register the click.
Did anyone manage to do something like that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A toast can not be clicked. It is not possible to capture a click inside a toast message.
You will need to build a dialog for that. Look at [Creating Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) for more info.

The API on the [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) class state that a toast will never receive the focus and because a toast is not a view there is no onClick message. I would assume that therefore childs of a Toast can not be clicked as well.

Comment: That's what I thought too. Ok thanks for the explanation. I know for the Dialogs, I was just doing some tests.

Comment: Perfect explanation and helped me out on the very first SO page I checked with this problem. Why isn't every answer the first thing you click!! :)

Answer (score 20):

A toast cant contain a button. Except that the gmail app and the gallery app in jelly beans have a semi toast that contains a button, here is how Google did it

https://gist.github.com/benvd/4090998

I guess this answers your question.

Comment: your link is invalid

Comment: This new link is working, instead of down-voting you could have googled the class name (UndoBarController.java), the repos were moved and that is not my fault.

Comment: In correct links are not appreciated in answers. Sure, I'll take care new time. Removed the downvote.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration

Answer (score 9):

Snippet shows implementation of custom Toast that:

[image: Header]

- Have similar interface as original `Toast` class
- Can be used as `Dialog` (have clickable buttons like Gmail app)
- Have possibility to set `length` in `millis`
- Have possibility to set show and cancel animation
- Lives only with initialized `Activity`

Current Limitations:

- No screen orientation change are supported

#### Usage:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //...

    View toastView = new View(getBaseContext());
    //init your toast view

    ActivityToast toast = new ActivityToast(this, toastView);

    //set toast Gravity ( Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL by default)
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    toast.setLength(10000); //set toast show duration to 10 seconds (2 seconds by default)

    Animation showAnim; // init animation
    Animation.AnimationListener showAnimListener; //init anim listener
    toast.setShowAnimation(showAnim);
    toast.setShowAnimationListener(showAnimListener);

    Animation cancelAnim; // init animation
    Animation.AnimationListener cancelAnimListener; //init anim listener
    toast.setCancelAnimation(showAnim);
    toast.setCancelAnimationListener(showAnimListener);

    toast.show(); //show toast view
    toast.isShowing(); // check if toast is showing now
    toast.cancel(); //cancel toast view

    toast.getView(); //get toast view to update it or to do something ..
}
```

#### Sources

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class ActivityToast {

    public static final long LENGTH_SHORT = 2000;
    public static final long LENGTH_LONG = 3000;
    public static final int DEFAULT_ANIMATION_DURATION = 400;

    private final Activity mActivity;
    private FrameLayout.LayoutParams mLayoutParams;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private ViewGroup mParent;
    private FrameLayout mToastHolder;
    private View mToastView;

    private Animation mShowAnimation;
    private Animation mCancelAnimation;

    private long mLength = LENGTH_SHORT;

    private Animation.AnimationListener mShowAnimationListener;
    private Animation.AnimationListener mCancelAnimationListener;

    private boolean mIsAnimationRunning;
    private boolean mIsShown;

    /**
     * @param activity Toast will be shown at top of the widow of this Activity
     */
    public ActivityToast(@NonNull Activity activity, View toastView) {
        mActivity = activity;

        mParent = (ViewGroup) activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        mToastHolder = new FrameLayout(activity.getBaseContext());
        mLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL
        );
        mToastHolder.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);

        mShowAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        mShowAnimation.setDuration(DEFAULT_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        mShowAnimation.setAnimationListener(mHiddenShowListener);

        mCancelAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        mCancelAnimation.setDuration(DEFAULT_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        mCancelAnimation.setAnimationListener(mHiddenCancelListener);

        mToastView = toastView;
        mToastHolder.addView(mToastView);

        mToastHolder.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    cancel();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void show() {
        if (!isShowing()) {
            mParent.addView(mToastHolder);
            mIsShown = true;

            if (mShowAnimation != null) {
                mToastHolder.startAnimation(mShowAnimation);
            } else {
                mHandler.postDelayed(mCancelTask, mLength);
            }
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        if (isShowing() && !mIsAnimationRunning) {
            if (mCancelAnimation != null) {
                mToastHolder.startAnimation(mCancelAnimation);
            } else {
                mParent.removeView(mToastHolder);
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mCancelTask);
                mIsShown = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isShowing() {
        return mIsShown;
    }

    /**
     * Pay attention that Action bars is the part of Activity window
     *
     * @param gravity Position of view in Activity window
     */

    public void setGravity(int gravity) {
        mLayoutParams.gravity = gravity;

        if (isShowing()) {
            mToastHolder.requestLayout();
        }
    }

    public void setShowAnimation(Animation showAnimation) {
        mShowAnimation = showAnimation;
    }

    public void setCancelAnimation(Animation cancelAnimation) {
        mCancelAnimation = cancelAnimation;
    }

    /**
     * @param cancelAnimationListener cancel toast animation. Note: you should use this instead of
     *                                Animation.setOnAnimationListener();
     */
    public void setCancelAnimationListener(Animation.AnimationListener cancelAnimationListener) {
        mCancelAnimationListener = cancelAnimationListener;
    }

    /**
     * @param showAnimationListener show toast animation. Note: you should use this instead of
     *                              Animation.setOnAnimationListener();
     */
    public void setShowAnimationListener(Animation.AnimationListener showAnimationListener) {
        mShowAnimationListener = showAnimationListener;
    }

    public void setLength(long length) {
        mLength = length;
    }

    public View getView() {
        return mToastView;
    }

    private Runnable mCancelTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            cancel();
        }
    };

    private Animation.AnimationListener mHiddenShowListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            if (mShowAnimationListener != null) {
                mShowAnimationListener.onAnimationStart(animation);
            }

            mIsAnimationRunning = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mCancelTask, mLength);

            if (mShowAnimationListener != null) {
                mShowAnimationListener.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            }

            mIsAnimationRunning = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            if (mShowAnimationListener != null) {
                mShowAnimationListener.onAnimationRepeat(animation);
            }
        }
    };

    private Animation.AnimationListener mHiddenCancelListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            if (mCancelAnimationListener != null) {
                mCancelAnimationListener.onAnimationStart(animation);
            }

            mIsAnimationRunning = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mParent.removeView(mToastHolder);
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mCancelTask);

            if (mCancelAnimationListener != null) {
                mCancelAnimationListener.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            }

            mIsAnimationRunning = false;
            mIsShown = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            if (mCancelAnimationListener != null) {
                mCancelAnimationListener.onAnimationRepeat(animation);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

[My original post on github](https://github.com/yakivmospan/android-codeview/blob/gh-pages/gists/view/activity-toast.md)
[Post that shows implementation of custom layout in this post](https://github.com/yakivmospan/android-codeview/blob/gh-pages/gists/view/activity-toast-factory.md)

Comment: Thanks, but just discovered materials :) snackbar is just the same

Comment: It was added in new support library, few weeks ago.

Answer (score 5):

A custom view passed to a toast can contain anything; however, toasts cannot receive any touch events so no components that use touch events will work in a stock toast (buttons, radiobuttons, etc.). The only choice you have is to create a custom view with a button in it and add it to your layout. There are many examples of how to do this and a few libraries you can check out to see how other people are doing it.

[UndoBar](https://github.com/soarcn/UndoBar) 
[MessageBar](https://github.com/SimonVT/MessageBar) 
[Nurik's UndoBar](https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/undobar)

Of course you are also welcome to use the [SuperToasts](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts) library I put together however it might be a little overkill for one usage. The way that I do it is outlined in the [SuperActivityToast](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts/blob/master/supertoasts/src/com/github/johnpersano/supertoasts/SuperActivityToast.java) class.

Answer (score 4):

You should use a `Snackbar`. It is in the latest android support library(at time of answer) and is compatible with older api levels. It is much easier to implement than a `Dialog` or custom `View` and has the ability to have a button unlike a `Toast`.

1. Download `Android Support Library` from `Extras` in the `SDK Manager`(revision 22.2.1 or later).
2. In the `build.gradle` add this to the class dependencies: `com.android.support:design:22.2.0`.
3. Implement:

   `Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Toast Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
   .setAction("Click here to activate action", onClickListener)
   .setActionTextColor(Color.RED)
   .show;`

And that is it. No github projects and implementation is very similiar to `Toast`. I used it in one of my projects and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [SuperToast](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts) in this case. It can create toast with button. It has custom duration feature, colourful background, colourful fonts, custom fonts, animated effect. Hope u will enjoy it

Answer (score 1):

Use an alertbox, if you want to add a button :-). Here are some examples
[Dialog boxes in Android](http://huuah.com/dialog-boxes-in-android/)

Answer (score 1):

[Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)

This is suggesting that it can be done, I also need buttons in a toast so I still have to make my own implementation. If I find more I will add it to my post