# Can i put buttons on Toast message in Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android : Button in custom Toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308975/android-button-in-custom-toast)

HI,i have create toast message,now i want to create buttons on it,please give suggestions to achieve it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308975/android-button-in-custom-toast

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom toast message.. Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)....

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to guess "no" because they only accept a String to be displayed.  There'd be no way to get the button included and also have a click listenener, etc.

Comment: Thats not completly true, you can in fact display a custom toast. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView

Comment: Very cool.  My answer was by no means definitive.  I learn something new every day.  I knew about custom Toast messages.  I just don't see how to get everything wired up.  Hopefully this question will bare fruit.