# Android Toast with Button

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android : Button in custom Toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308975/android-button-in-custom-toast)

I did custom Toast message in text view. i want to include button over that toast message. is  that possible to insert button over custom toast message. If there is a possibility pls guide me.

Comment: Hello all, i googled out about this problem and i got this tutorial. Just see this : http://www.samcoles.co.uk/mobile/android-custom-toast-notification/ ..i dont know but what if in place of  image i put a button and in xml itself, i can set onClickListener..Will it run correctly ?..Its just a guess...

Comment: Yeah you are rite, same tutorial i also read some while, and i tried to implement Button over that. but onclick listener will not functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not Possible use a Dialog Box Insted.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate reply, is that possible to give time limit for to show the dialog box like a toast message. in Toast we can give Toast.Long or Shot. As per the time  limit it will display the message. is this possible in dialog box..?? or else any other option for display the time limit message with button, like toast message,