# How can I include a button in a Toast notification?

Tags: android

First of all, I know this has been asked before: [Button in custom Android Toast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308975/android-button-in-custom-toast).
This is nearly an exact duplicate, but I think that it warrants a new question based on the fact that it's been used in apps, namely Gmail for ICS (it appears when you delete a message).

The linked question says that it's not possible to include a button in a `Toast` because `Toast`s cannot be focused. Is this wrong, outdated, or did Gmail find a way around it?

Comment: You could use a dialog anyway...

Comment: What `Toast` in Gmail are you referring to? And, more to the point, how did you prove that it is a `Toast`?

Comment: I've just tried Gmail on ICS and I couldn't find in what case it gives a toast with a button in it. Besides with a custom Dialog, or a custom transparent Activity with Dialog on it, it should be really easy to mimic the look and behavior of a Toast which is virtually indistinguishable from the real thing.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hmm... good point. I suppose I should be more sure that it's actually a `Toast` first.

Comment: "a Toast appears with text and an "Undo" button" -- that's not a `Toast`. For starters, it is there indefinitely, or until you touch something else, whereas a `Toast` vanishes after a period of time. If I had to guess, that is a simple `ViewGroup` floating over top the main activity (by being a later child in a `RelativeLayout`, perhaps).

Comment: @CommonsWare OK - thanks for your help! I probably should have researched this problem before asking it so quickly. You should contribute that as an answer because although it doesn't strictly qualify as a `Toast`, to the user it looks like a `Toast` for all intents and purposes (I was fooled!).

Comment: My answer was deleted because I gave the same answer to multiple questions, but I think it would have really helped. Gmail uses a `Snackbar` for that. It is much easier than a custom `View` or `Dialog` and is very easy to implement. Check [here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-snackbar-example/) for setup tutorial and [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design) for implementation. By the way @MartijnPieters I edited my question. I would appreciate if you look at it and undelete it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The accepted answer for this question also has the same answer as a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308975/button-in-custom-android-toast/12025517#12025517).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The Gmail undo bar is't a toast, here is how Google did it

http://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/undobar/src/com/example/android/undobar/UndoBarController.java

I guess this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

What you're referring to is not a Toast but what Google has dubbed a Snackbar. See the [Material Design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html).

You can find [several implementations](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=snackbar%20android) of this on GitHub. [Some](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android%20undobar) also go by the name of UndoBar

Currently, the most extensive, popular, and active one seems to be [Snackbar by nispok](https://github.com/nispok/snackbar), which I also happen to be using.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a button in a toast, its better you quit that idea. But you can use dialogs in place of toast. Using dailogs, you will be able to display whatever you want (same function as a toast would do). Also in the dailog, you could set buttons.

Comment: Although  a dialog _would_ work in my case, I'd much rather have a Toast because they are much less obtrusive -- going back to the Gmail example, a Toast appears with text and an "Undo" button, because it is unlikely that they would want to undo it. A dialog would become quite annoying if one popped up every time you wanted to delete messages.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail on iOS does provide a toast and it is a much better solution than interrupting the user flow with a dialog.

![Toast style message in Gmail for iOS][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWClq.jpg

If you use this option, make sure the toast is displayed long enough for the user to tap undo if needed. So 5 seconds as opposed to 2.5-3 seconds in a info-only toast.

The other example cited by CommonsWare is the inline feedback which is shown after a swipe gesture. This is not a toast- but it is also a great way to provide feedback that an action has been performed.

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the UndoBar mentioned by @Hazem ([link](https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/undobar/?r=72667b28282e0a366c4bc96fa26522fb7cac29de)) and made it more generic so that it can be used for other actions also. You can have a look [here](http://blog.ashwanik.in/2015/01/extending-android-undobar.html).