# Toast with button in Android

Tags: android, android-button, toast

How to implement toast with button as shown below? It is used in recent Google apps in Android.

[image]

Comment: for ref: [Customize toast](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/customiozing-toast-in-android.html) and an [SO question link regarding the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909476/how-to-customize-toast-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575520/how-can-i-include-a-button-in-a-toast-notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575520/how-can-i-include-a-button-in-a-toast-notification)

Comment: It's usually referred to as the [Undo Bar](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/RA9WEEGWYp6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom toast messages like this. This is a dialog will dismiss after 2.5 seconds just like a toast.

```
public class CustomToast extends Dialog {  
 public CustomToast(Context context, String text) {  
  super(context);  
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context  
  .getSystemService(android.content.Context.  
     LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
  
  View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast, null);  
  TextView tv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastText);  
  tv.setText(text);    
  setContentView(layout);  
  show();  
  setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);  
  setCancelable(true);  
  Window window = getWindow();  
  window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);  
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  
  
   public void run() {  
    dismiss();  
   }  
  }, 2500);  
 }  
}
```

Comment: Try using a `Snackbar` from Android Support Library.