# Android custom toast as in Facebook app

Tags: java, android, facebook, toast

Never messed with custom layout in Android.

What I'm basically trying to do is this:
[image]

The closest thing I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26437711/1334761), but didn't manage to make it work (tried for few hours and no result, it just won't show), and also it would require more work to make it look like the facebook's one.

I'd like to be able to call the toast everywhere from my app, too.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Btw, toasts with buttons/actions sound more like a [Snackbar](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) component from the new design library.

Comment: @Android777, thanks, this looks like the answer. I got another problem tho, I imported the design support library with resources to my workspace but I get lots of 'error: Error: No resource found that matches the given...' in the styles.xml. Any idea?