# Android Toast message callback or any event on touch

Tags: android, onclick, android-toast

When Android app shows a Toast message if the app is in the background, it goes to the notification tray. When we click it from the notification tray it brings the app in the foreground.

But when the app is in the foreground, it shows the message on the screen. If I click the message, it does nothing. I would like to take the user to some specific activity.

Mainly I want to handle the toast message click event. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: You can use `PendingIntent` for navigate to activity on Click of Notification

Comment: I don't get any click event for toast msg. That was the main problem how to get some event to handle it?

Comment: I don't know about Toast Click till now, but you can try set custom layout on Toast and try to set click event on that view.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3309066/7376885) you can not.

But you may take a look at snackbars or stick to toasts and use libraries that may deliver such results e.g. [Super Toasts](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts)

Comment: Super Toasts looks promising. Let me try. Thanks for the info